# Regarding calling an activity via Intent inside the Fragment

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to call the activity on click of text view.I have used the View Pager Adapter.
The class in which I am trying to call  The New Activity is

http://pastie.org/9684982

Kindly can anyone guide where exactly I am struck.How can i call activity on textview Climate Click
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);

    TextView Climate = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.txt_climate);

    Climate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),your_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

    return root;
}
```

Comment: I have applied the code.But its crashing.Actually I am doing coding in Android Studio for Android Wear Application.

Comment: Can you wait.I am working on Android Studio tool.Here I need to find where is error option which can track all the logs.